# Codeigniter How to fetch image in database after login

Tags: php, codeigniter

Good day every one i would like to ask who had an idea on how to fetch the picture of the user who had login. My aim here is to fetch the image of the user who had a uploaded a picture in the database. i had already fetch the fname and the lname,sessionid and the usertype.

This is my Login function validation

```
function validation()  
      {  
           $this->load->library('form_validation');  
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('idnumber', 'idnumber', 'required');  
           $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');  

           if($this->form_validation->run())  
           {  
               //true  
              $idnumber = $this->input->post('idnumber');
              $password = $this->input->post('password');

              $this->load->model('login_model');
              if ($this->login_model->can_login($idnumber, $password)) 
              {
                  $usertype = $this->session->userdata('usertype');
                  if($usertype == "3")
                  {
                     redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
                  }
                  else
                  {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');
                    redirect('login', 'refresh');
                  }
              }
              else 
              {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username and Password');
                redirect('login', 'refresh');
              }
           }
           else 
           {
              
                $this->index();
           }


      }
```

This is my Model

```
public function can_login($idnumber, $password)  
      {  
           $this->db->select('*');
           $this->db->from('tbl_users');
           $this->db->where('idnumber', $idnumber);  
           $this->db->where('password', $password);  
           $query = $this->db->get();
           //SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'  
            if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result_array() as $row) {
                $data['nameofuser'] = $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'];
                $data['full'] = $row['fname'] . " " . $row['mname']. " " . $row['lname'];
                $data['sessionid'] = $row['id'];
                $data['usertype'] = $row['usertype'];
            }
            $this->session->set_userdata($data);
            return true;
            } 
            else 
            {
              return false;
            }
      }
```

This my view i am using adminlte3

```
<div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
          i want to display the image here coming from the database
          <img src="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <p class="d-block"><?php echo $this->session->userdata('nameofuser');?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I am not seeing your users table schema to see the column for image name. You should fetch the image name first like others $row['fname'] from the table whether it was saved in users table or it can be any other table to save profile of user. After fetching the image name from table use the path for uploaded file like and put it in img src="base_url('images/image_name')" . Don't forget to replace the value of image and filepath .

Comment: You are already selecting everything (`*`) from `tbl_users`, so if your profile pic is a field in that table, you already have it ready to use.

Comment: I am wondering why you are fetching result via the `result_array()` function in the `foreach()`? Isn't `idnumber` and `password` supposed to fetch data for a single user? You could get single user data using `$query->row_array()` instead. And `foreach()` will not be needed in this case.